# Why is Zelda Tears of the Kingdom getting stuck and crashing while loading after loading shaders in YUZU?

Tags: emulation, zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

The game was working well in Yuzu but the problem starts when I click "Install Files to NAND" and then click on my Zelda `totk.xci` file. The game loading runs for a while then stops.

I tried everything from deleting Vulkan files and changing to OpenGL but nothing works.

Comment: Is this some sort of modding/homebrew?

Comment: @TimmyJim no actually this done mistakely